# Sorting a file with unix `sort` from a python script

Tags: python, sorting, unix

I'm processing some data with python, and I'd like to have the script run a result file through unix's `sort` command so I don't have to do it myself. I *could* write a small thesis in idiomatic python to do it, but *why*.

The data is in the form of:

```
100 1   194.388119205
100 10  61.6006956954
100 50  42.795157377
10  50  73.5057139073
1   1   14550.8877483
1   10  1480.57562914
```

I've been sucessfully using `sort -k 1 -k 2 -g file.txt -o file.txt` manually, but when I try to run that from the python script using `os.system`, `subprocess.Popen`, or `subprocess.call`, it does [absolutely nothing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GB7mHxdHlRY) to the file.

I've checked that the current working directory for each call is correct/set, that the files exist, and I'm using the `shell=True` option for the subprocess methods.

What gives?

EDIT: Code for those that want it

```
for file in glob.glob('lat*.txt'):
    cmd = "sort -k 1 -k 2 -g " + file + " -o " + file

    # This returns the correct directory
    print os.getcwd()
    assert(os.path.isfile(file))

    # If I run the output from this print statement in the shell, it works, 
    # so it's not the command or it's formatting
    print cmd

    # These do not sort the file
    os.system(cmd)
    subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)

    # I've even tried a version of sort without the output parameter, 
    # to see if I could get the output from stdout, but again, nothing.
    cmd = "sort -k 1 -k 2 -g " + file 
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in proc.stdout:
        print line
    proc.wait()
```

Comment: Please show the code you have been using. I suspect the file simply gets written to some unexpected location due to pwd being somewhere else than you expect it to be or something like that. This is hard to figure out without code.

Comment: neither `popen` nor `call` parse a string like that. you have to supply an array of arguments, but `os.system` should work... can you provide an example filename?

Comment: `lat_95.txt` is one of the filenames.